# Why does my RJS stop working when I set options in form_remote_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

I am running into a strange problem.
I simply want to display a loading icon on the page when pressing a button.
If my call to `form_remote_for` contains Ajax options then the RJS script does not work.

**This works** ("loading" is hidden by the controller and RJS):

*View:*

```
<%=form_remote_for(:job, @job, {:url => {:action=>:create}}) do |f| %>
[...]
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

*controller:*

```
def create  
  render :action => "create.js.rjs"   
end
```

*RJS:*

```
page.hide 'loading'
```

**This does not work** (just adding `:loading=>` and loading is shown by the view but not hidden back by the controller as it was before):

```
<%=form_remote_for(:job, @job, {:url => {:action=>:create}}, {:loading=>"$('loading').show()"}) do |f| %>
[...]
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
```

So if my call to `form_remote_for` contains Ajax options then the RJS script does not work. Why?

Comment: Mick, I updated my answer. See if it works for you, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form to:

```
<% form_remote_for (:job, @job, :url => {:action => :create}, :loading =>"$('loading').show()") do |f| %>
# ...
<% end %>
```

Make sure create is:

```
  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.xml
  def create
    render :action => "create.js.rjs"
  end
```

And make sure your create.js.rjs is:

```
page.hide 'loading'
```

This scenario works for me.  As you had it, it was returning the erb in the template because it was posting to "new" -- based on a quick scaffold implementation I did.  Now I might still be missing something because as I said before the massive edit, I'm new, but this should get you going.

EDIT: Removed "is this your code?" post.

Comment: I don't understand why
- it work when not using RJS (with braces)
- it does not when using RJS (still with braces)
- and removing the braces it works with RJS

Comment: When the braces are removed it posts back to /jobs and with the braces it posts back to /jobs/new -- not the intended location.  I don't know enough to answer why, I just noted observed behavior.  Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly answering your question of "why" it isn't working, have you looked at using the `:loaded` parameter to hide the loading DIV rather than rely on the `rjs` file?

Comment: It works well with `:loaded` and I am using it often. But sometimes when your controller logic and your client javascript is complex, it works better with RJS. My example was simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using prototype you should use the Ajax.Responders to do the show/hide:

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onCreate: function() {
    Ajax.activeRequestCount++;
        if($('loading') && Ajax.activeRequestCount>0) {
      Effect.Appear('loading',{duration:0.4,queue:'end'});
        };          
  },
  onComplete: function() {
    Ajax.activeRequestCount--;
        if($('loading') && Ajax.activeRequestCount==0) {
        Effect.Fade('loading',{duration:0.4,queue:'end'});
        };    
  }
});
```

You can stick it in public/javascripts/application.js

Unobtrusive javascript - will work on any page with a hidden loading div and ajax events.